# ERROR: Function not implemented on requests from Angular frontend to Spring Boot backend

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, spring, spring-boot

I've created a user registration app frontend in Angular which seems to have the proper code for POST register method to be called & data to be sent to backend for user registration but I get the error: Function not implemented in my browser console. The spring boot works fine on sending requests from POSTMAN but gives error "Email already in use 400 Bad request" even though the email sent through angular form is not present in my SQL database.

Sharing the frontend code as well as browser console & spring boot console message.

register.component.html

```
<div class="registrationForm" type="FormGroup">
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">


<div class="form-row">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputUsername">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fname"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername" placeholder="eg. John" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputUsername">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lname"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername" placeholder="eg. Doe" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
  </div>

</div>

<div class="form-row">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email" name="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="eg. john@gmail.com" required >
  </div>
  <!--
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" required class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="eg. john@gmail.com">
  </div>
  -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
  </div>

</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:220px;margin-top:20px;">Submit</button>
```

register.component.ts

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/register/userservice'; //import the user service
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'; //import form modules
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.less']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  registrationForm: FormGroup;
  email:string ='';
  password:string ='';
  fname:string ='';
  lname:string ='';
  submitted = false;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private UserService: UserService,
  )
 {
  this.registrationForm = this.formBuilder.group({});
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registrationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: [this.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: [this.password, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
      fname: [this.fname],
      lname: [this.lname],
    });
  }

  // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() { return this.registrationForm.controls; }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('Submit button clicked');
    this.submitted = true;

    this.UserService.register(
    this.registrationForm.controls['email'].value, 
    this.registrationForm.controls['password'].value, 
    this.registrationForm.controls['fname'].value, 
    this.registrationForm.controls['lname'].value)
    .pipe(
      tap((response: any) => console.log('Response from server:', response)),
      catchError((error: any) => {
        console.log('Error from server:', error);
        return throwError(error);
      })
    )
    .subscribe();
    
  }

  }
  
function throwError(error: any): any {
  throw new Error('Function not implemented.');
}
```

userservice.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080'; // replace with your backend URL //backend url for post mapping of user details

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //check the use of 'Observable'
  register(email: string, password: string, fname: string,lname: string): Observable<any> {
    const data = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
      fname: fname,
      lname: lname
    };
    console.log('User service register method called with user:', data);
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/api/register`, data);
  }
}
```

My browser console message:
[Browser console error: POST 400, Function not implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0mRY.png)

My Spring boot console message:
[Spring Boot log: Bad Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY0P7.png)

Kindly tell how to solve this.

Comment: Here you're using Template driven form in html but in typescript you're using reactive form & binding value from template driven to reactive form, which basically not seems to work. Can you confirm me that, you're getting proper data from form via 'this.registrationForm.controls['lname'].value)' this ?

Comment: Instead of the current implementation you can do this, `this.UserService.register(
   this.email, this.password, this.fname, this.lname).pipe(...)` rest of the implementation should remain same.